# Query on Collator and RuleBasedCollator present in java.text package

Tags: java

What is Collator and RuleBasedCollator present in java.text package? When do we use it in real world scenarios?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Collator` class lets you compare strings in a local-sensitive way. This allows your application to sort strings in an order that makes sense to users from different countries.

For example, [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/locale.html) shows how the same list of strings gets sorted in a different order depending on the selected locale.

The `RuleBasedCollator` class is a concrete implementation of `Collator`. You typically wouldn't use it directly, unless you needed to define you own sorting order. For more details, see [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/rule.html).